# Set propperties from an object to another 'similar' object in C#

Tags: c#, clone

I have two objects like:

```
class HOUSE_MODEL
{
   int RoomSize,
   int NumberOfBaths
   int GarageSize  
}

class DB_HOUSE_ENTITY
{
   int RoomSize,
   int NumberOfBaths
   int NumberOfDoors
}
```

I want Create a HOUSE_MODEL object and copy all values of the DB_HOUSE_ENTITY object if the property have the same name in both objects (in this case i would like copy roomSize and NumberOfBaths properties).

There is anyway to do this without copy one to one properties from one object to the other?

thanks in advance.

Comment: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), perhaps?

Comment: I Use Omu.ValueInjecter: https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ - copies fields and properties with same names, even bewteen classes that do not have the same structure.

Comment: Charles, that is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of doing this is to create copy constructors:

```
public class HouseModel
{
   int RoomSize,
   int NumberOfBaths
   int GarageSize  

   public HouseModel( DbHouseModel model )
   {
       RoomSize = model.RoomSize;
       NumberOfBaths = model.NumberOfBaths; 
   }
}
```

This has some advantages over mappers, particularly it causes a compile time error if someone changes the name of a member of one of the classes but forgets to do it to the other.

Comment: The problem is when instead of 2 properties, both objects have 20 properties with same name... i think a 'copy constructor' is not the best  way for do that